# No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"forum"} missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to route the thredded /forum to a link on the nav bar but this bug is holding me back. Not sure if its an installation issue or a pathing one. Thanks!

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :links
  mount Thredded::Engine => '/forum' # creates about_path
  resources :forum
  devise_for :users
  root "pages#home"
  get "about" => "pages#about"
end
```

**home page / _header.html.erb**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <%= link_to "Rowlund", root_path, class: "navbar-brand" %>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div class="container">
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->

          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Forum", forum_path%></li>
          <li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
          <% if user_signed_in? %>
            <li><%= link_to "Account Settings", edit_user_registration_path %> </li>
            <li><%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, method:     :delete %></li>
          <% else %>
            <li><%= link_to "Log in", new_user_session_path %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
       </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run `rake routes` or `rake routes | grep forum`, you should find the following route in the list of routes.

```
forum GET    /forums/:id(.:format)          forums#show
```

The route `/forums/:id` maps to `forums#show` and you need to pass in an `id` in the url. For eg:

```
forums_path(3) => /forums/3
forums_path(Forum.find(1)) => /forums/1
```

In your code, you're not passing a `id` to `forum_path`.That is why you're getting the error `missing required keys: [:id]`

Since you don't have a particular `forum` object to map in your navbar links, you should better map the link to the `index` action. Change the following link

```
<li><%= link_to "Forum", forum_path %></li>
```

to

```
<li><%= link_to "Forum", forums_path %></li>
```

Note that `forums_path` maps to `forums#index`